# Is it possible to manually configure CodeBuild and CodeDeploy, and then generate CloudFormation template(s) from that?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

My immediate goal is to get CI/CD up and running for a project, with an ultimate goal of having infrastructure-as-a-code using CloudFormation for CodeBuild and CodeDeploy. Starting with CloudFormation from zero turned out to be an uphill battle. I'm wondering, would it be possible to manually configure CodeBuild and CodeDeploy using AWS console,  generate CloudFormation template(s) from that, and then iterate in the templates? Any existing tools or approaches?

Tried building CloudFormation template for CodeBuild and CodeDeploy, and it is taking days to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing on AWS that allows you to do that, so you could try using open source project [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2). Both CodeBuild and CodeDeploy resources should be supported according to the [documentation](https://github.com/iann0036/former2/blob/master/RESOURCE_COVERAGE.md).